# I want to search location in google maps and get latitude and longitude programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm currently developing program that needs to display the location and map and get the latitude and longitude.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. I have edit text which will be used by user to search the location.
2. I want to display the location in the map.
3. get the latitude and longitude.

I know google maps can do that, but when I've tried the sample code from google but it only showing the map. I want to add the searching function for my program, is it possible to do that?

Comment: You can use the GeoCoder for location searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so here is your complete solution.add below code where you want to get location

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
                @Override
                public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Latitude=location.getLatitude();
                    longitude=location.getLongitude();
                    Log.d("latitude",""+Latitude);
                    Log.d("latitude",""+longitude);
                }
            };
            MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
            myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```

and create a class MyLocation to find location lat long

```
package com.example.util;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.pgapplication.SearchResultActivity;

public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(SearchResultActivity searchResultActivity, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) searchResultActivity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(),0);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
            if(gps_enabled)
                gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(network_enabled)
                net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            //if there are both values use the latest one
            if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }

            if(gps_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                return;
            }
            if(net_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to show it on the google maps? any idea?. thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: create marker and use lat log to plot it on google map